# Checking Nginx log on Docker local environment on Cloud version?

Tags: nginx, magento2-cloud

I'm working on `Magento Cloud` version, but I'm having an error with `502 Bad Gateway` on **nginx**.

```
502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.9.15
```

My question is that how to check the **nginx** log on Docker local environment?

Answer (score 1):

**502 error**

nginx upstream not available.
you need to check nginx proxy / php block in configuration.

nginx php upstream wrong port defined,
socket permissions,
upstream not running,
firewall blocking,

error log you can see in nginx config:

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/#error_log
https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html?#error_log

```
error_log /path/to/folder/with/error.log;
```

Comment: Did you work on Cloud version with Docker on local?

Comment: how does that help you ??

Comment: just go to container and check log, but the problem in upstream misconfiguration.

Comment: Oh, how to check it in the container?